# "502 Bad Gateway" with CloudBees Play2 Deployment (Java and Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, cloudbees

I followed the instructions described here to deploy my Play2 application to CloudBees: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework

My Build.scala settings looks like this:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA)
        .settings(cloudBeesSettings :_*)
        .settings(CloudBees.applicationId := Some("application"))
        .settings(CloudBees.username := Some("username"))
        .settings(CloudBees.apiKey := Some("0123456789ABCDEF"))
        .settings(CloudBees.apiSecret := Some("88888889999999$999999998888888="))
        .settings(CloudBees.host := "https://api.cloudbees.com/api")
        .settings(
          // Add your own project settings here  
        )
```

However, I get the following message when deploying:

```
[info] Deploying application-1.0-SNAPSHOT to Run@Cloud/username/application
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...
....[info] Application available at http://application.username.cloudbees.net
[error] {file:/Users/user/dev/play2/Application/application/}Application/*:cloudbees-deploy: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] Total time: 74 s, completed Feb 3, 2013 7:44:43 PM
```

And when I visit http://application.username.cloudbees.net, I get a "502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.2.0" error...

I'm thinking this is because I'm using a Mac, which has Java 1.7, and CloudBees is expecting 1.6...? From the sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin project source, I can see where I can set a "deployParams" option as a Map, but I'm completely new to Scala and am unsure how to do so. I want to do something like in Build.scala, but I keep getting errors:

```
.settings(CloudBees.deployParams += ("java_version" -> "1.7"))
```

The java_version parameter is described here: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/JVMVersion

You can see the source of the project here: https://github.com/CloudBees-community/sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/cloudbees.scala

I'm at a loss at what to do or what could be wrong with my deployment? Even when creating a brand new Play application with no database connections it continues to fail.

Any insight into what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the options.

```
CloudBees.deployParams := Map("runtime.java_version" -> "1.7"),
CloudBees.openOnUpload := false,
```

The first option sets the runtime to java 1.7 which is probably your issue. If sbt is using JDK7 then you will need to set the RUN@cloud platform to java 7.

The second option fixes the `ExceptionInInitializerError` by disabling the browser opening on deploy. In my experience this error points to Java 7 being used on your computer because I've only seen this error with Java 7 and not Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Also - always remember to look at the logs for your app, either via the web console or the bees app:tail command, in case it is failing in some container specific way (we can't return a non 500 error, and don't want to leak information about your error via the web, hence it is a generic error in that case).